# Pragma no cache and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, http-headers

Does the pragma no-cache mean the browser will not cache javascript scripts?

e.g.
    
    
Will the pragma no cache tag stop the browser from caching the jquery script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, that depends on the browser used. For modern browsers you need to add `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers as well.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

#### See also:

- [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)

Comment: Actually I want to cache javascript scripts but nothing else...Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Create a `Filter` which does the job in `doFilter()` method and map it on an URL pattern of `*.js`.

Comment: Depends upon the web server you're using, @DD.