# Refresh parent page

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a simple piece of code that if a user clicks cancel, then they are returned to the previous page using the attached code. What I would like to do is, if a user clicks the cancel button, then refresh the page they came from. Is this possible? Many thanks

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;" />
```

Comment: What's the difference? If they click refresh they are returned to the previous page but you want it to "refresh the page they came from" isn't that the same? I'm not sure you are using the word refresh correctly.

Comment: @Celeritas it is not exactly the same, because browsers mostly load pages from cache and not from server, of course it depends on user settings, but by default they load from cache

Comment: Hi. Not it's not the same. When they return, all the old data is still present. That is why I need to refresh. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use `meta` tags suggested in previous answer or check the `document.referrer` property against a specific URL and than refresh it manually via javascript.

**edit**

in 1.html you will have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(document.referrer.indexOf("files.php") != -1) {
        window.location.reload(true); // passing true as an argument causes page to being force loaded from the server
    }
});
```

and in the 2.html you just need this:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;" />
```

Comment: I am not sure I have coded this correctly as it is not working. When the button is clicked, nothing happens. <input type="button" value="Cancel" onClick="if(document.referrer == "files.php") {window.location.reload(true); // passing true as an argument causes page to being force loaded from the server
}"  /> Thanks

Comment: you should place this not on the button click, but in the document.load event of page what you want to reload, if you use jQuery, this will look like: `$(document).ready(function(){ // and the code from above });`

Comment: also use the whole URL when comparing, not only the part `files.php`, or you can if the document.referrer contains or ends with `files.php` but not equals, because it will return an absolute URL

Comment: I am not using Jquery. So i put it in function and just called it the onclick event: GoBack(); Still nothing.

Comment: if you don't use jQuery, then take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235985/attach-a-body-onload-event-with-js and add an event listernet to the first page

Answer (score 1):

window.parent.document.location.reload(); i think may work with jQuery. Set up a bind for the back button.

or throw this

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

in the head of the first page so it expires and will auto refresh

however I am not 100% sure that will work with firefox. It seems to work with
 IE.

I think you could also open a page without AJAX by making the rel = external

```
<a href="../index.html" data-icon="grid"
class="ui-btn-right" rel="external">Home</a>
```

that an old school way to do it.

Also  [`This is a very useful link explaining how jquery can accomplish this in most browsers`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201406/1255713). Probaly a more optimal solution rather then my hacks.

Comment: `window.parent.document.location.reload();` is not the solution because here the operation takes place in the same window and when you're going back in history the window object is the same so you can't access to the window object of previously opened page, anyway +1 for `meta` tags

Comment: but who said that he uses AJAX? I will say he definitely doesn't use AJAX as he speaks about `history.go(-1)`

Comment: @Bob. The meta code did not work.  Also, there is no AJAX. Thanks

Comment: which browser are you trying to get it to work with. you put that meta code in your html right?

Comment: @Bob. I have tried firefox,chrome,ie8. I put the code in the head section.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is if you're only concerned with reloading pages from your website you could force no caching. If you're interested [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208715/pragma-no-cache-and-javascript).

Comment: Even tried: response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies. Still not work.

Comment: You tried it on the page they were coming from right? Not the page that would be sending them back. I'm surprised it didn't work but if you've got it working a different way never mind.